# Having issues with opening windows terminal

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, command

whenever I open terminal, my windows power shell opens. I tried turning it off and on again from app aliases. but did not fix. these two are not same , which I knew online.my problem is I want to open terminal in my windows 11 , but how?

i tried turning terminal off and on again from app aliases. I expected it would work.

Comment: What shell do you want to use instead?

Comment: Did you run `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Terminal is just a user interface that can host different shells such as cmd or PowerShell. You can change the default shell in the settings of the terminal app. Right-click on the titlebar > settings, then set the standard profile to whatever.